# tcolorbox's \tcblower cannot be copied

Tags: tcolorbox

`tcolorbox`'s `\tcblower` cannot be copied as shown by the following MCE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\NewCommandCopy{\mytcblower}{\tcblower}
\ShowCommand{\mytcblower}
\begin{document}
\begin{tcolorbox}
  Foo
  \mytcblower
  Bar
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

Do you understand why and is there a way around this impossibility?

Comment: why impossibility? it is not defined yet, so you get as expected a copy of an undefined command.

Comment: Isn't it defined as soon as `tcolorbox` is loaded?

Comment: well obviously not. Try \ShowCommand\tcblower

Comment: That's what I did in my MCE. Does it mean `\tcblower` is defined only inside a tcolorbox (and friends)?

Comment: yes, but why does it suprise you so much? I mean you know that one can define commands everywhere.

Comment: I had the hope to replace `\tcblower` by something more meaningful for a custom `tcolorbox`.

Comment: You can just say `\newcommand{\mytcblower}{\tcblower}`. Then the definition of `\tcblower` at the point when you issue `\newcommand` does not matter. The command will just use the definition of `\tcblower` at the time of use. (Ulrike already said it, but `\tcblower` is only defined inside your colorbox. That makes sense, because outside of this environment the command couldn't do anything useful.)

Comment: @moewe That makes sense indeed.